# UIWebView behaves differently on iPhone4 and iPhone5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My app uses UIWebView to transmit control messages via WiFi to a remote device. A message consists of HTML header, an IP address and a CGI command. The IP address matches the static address of the target device. WiFi settings also indicate there is a connection to a static IP address via a wireless router (i.e. Airport Express).

Even though the iPhone status bar shows no WiFi icon, the code appears to work reliably on iPhone4 running either iOS6 or iOS7. But it refuses to work on iPhone5 or iPhone5C.

These are the constants:

```
static NSString* const HTTP       = @"http:/";        // CGI header
static NSString* const ip         = @"192.168.50.87"; // ip address
static NSString* const INITIALISE = @"rc.cgi?c=99";   // Switch device
```

And here is the method:

```
- (void)loadInitialise {
UIWebView *initialise         = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSString *switchInit          = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", HTTP, ip, INITIALISE];
NSLog(@"%@", switchInit);

NSURL *webURL                 = [NSURL URLWithString: switchInit];
NSURLRequest *webURLRequest   = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];

[initialise loadRequest:webURLRequest];
```

Can someone explain why UIWebView might work on an iPhone4 but not an iPhone5. Thanks.

Comment: And why aren't you using NSURLConnection or AFNetworking for this? Why a webview if you aren't displaying anything?

Comment: A good point. I used UIWebView initially believing that eventually I might need to display something. I continued to use UIWebView simply because it appeared to work until I used it with iPhone5. Right now I'll try any alternative so thanks.